# How would I construct a mysql query to use multiple AND operators?

Tags: php, mysql

eg `"SELECT * FROM date WHERE name = 'etc' AND lastname = 'etc' AND etc='etc'";`

Comment: Question is not clear. You have already constructed a query.

Comment: what exactly is the question here?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean, How would I construct a mysql query to use multiple AND operators using a language other than SQL. If that *is* what you mean, better say so...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do it exactly like you just said.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking to construct query based on PHP input variables

```
$fields = array( "name", "lastname", "etc" ) ;
foreach( $fields as $field)
{
   $clause[]=$field."='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field])."'";
}
$query = "SELECT * from `date` where "
         .implode( " AND ", $clause );
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll do it like this

```
eg "SELECT * FROM date WHERE name = 'etc' AND lastname = 'etc' AND etc='etc'";
```