# how can i configure/apply condition to my query to get the result?

Tags: php, mysql

How can i configure to my query.

```
$query_event ="SELECT * FROM event_list WHERE even_title='$EventTitle' AND even_loc='$EventLocation' ";
```

now suppose there is form which requires either put title or put location in the form or u can put both and for blank too so what will be the query?

Please help

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I construct a mysql query to use multiple AND operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687530/how-would-i-construct-a-mysql-query-to-use-multiple-and-operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a starting query, then add on where clauses

```
$query_event = "Select * from event_list where 1";

if ( $EventTitle ) {
    $query_event .= " and even_title='$EventTitle'";
}

if ( $event_loc ) {
    $query_event .= " and even_loc='$EventLocation'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass your queries this way, you're going to be very vulnerable to SQL injection.

For example, if someone type `"'; DELETE FROM EVENT_LIST"` as an Event title in a search screen, he can delete your whole table.

Use these advices to protect your datas :
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Top_5#P3:_SQL_Injection